# Clickable Radio Button List in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

How do i make these radio buttons clickable that takes me to specific page in other words when one of the options is clicked it should take me to my home page.  Each option should take me to a different page.

```
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio"  name="optradio"/>Option 1</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"/>Option 2</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio"/>Option 3</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's a complete markup of what you are trying to accomplish:

```js
window.onload = function() {

        var ex1 = document.getElementById('example1');
        var ex2 = document.getElementById('example2');
        var ex3 = document.getElementById('example3');

        ex1.onclick = handler1;
        ex2.onclick = handler2;
        ex3.onclick = handler3;

    }

    function handler1() {
        window.location.replace('http://www.example.com');
    }
 function handler2() {
        window.location.replace('http://www.sample.com');
    }
 function handler3() {
        window.location.replace('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stack.css"/>
 </head>
<body>
<html>
 <head>
   
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="radio" name="example1" id="example1" value="Example 1" />
  <label for="example1">Example 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="example2" id="example2" value="Example 2" />
  <label for="example1">Example 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="example3" id="example3" value="Example 3" />
  <label for="example1">Example 3</label>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, each option should take me to a different page

Comment: Edited. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the URL you want it to take you to in a `data` attribute of the tag, then assign an event handler to the button to take you there when you click on it.

```js
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('radioLink');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('change',function() {
      window.location.href = this.dataset.url;
    });
  }
```

```html
<label class="radio-inline"><input class="radioLink" type="radio"  name="optradio" data-url="/asdf.html" />Option 1</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input class="radioLink" type="radio" name="optradio" data-url="http://stackoverflow.com" />Option 2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels weird without a button. With jQuery and a button like this:

```
$("#go_to_url").click(function() {
  var url = $('input[name=optradio]:checked', '#myForm').val()
  window.location = url;
});
```

Form:

```
<form id="myForm">
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="http://google.com" checked>Option 1</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="http://google.com">Option 2</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="http://google.com">Option 3</label>
<button id="go_to_url">take me there</button>
</form>
```